# gpg is promting for passphrase even after passphrase is set using gpg-preset-passphrase

Tags: gnupg

I need to preset the passhrase to decrypt credentials on an unattended machine.

I executed the below steps, even after the passphrase is preset gpg is prompting for password for the private key.

```
gpg --batch --allow-secret-key-import --import './test_private.key'
/usr/libexec/gpg-preset-passphrase --preset --passphrase "password" "KeygripID"
```

I am using gpg version2

```
bash-5.0# gpg --version
gpg (GnuPG) 2.2.23
libgcrypt 1.8.5
Copyright (C) 2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <https://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Home: /root/.gnupg
```

Currently executing above steps in a docker container

```
bash-5.0# cat /etc/alpine-release
3.12.0
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please see [**This Q&A**](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/60213/gpg-asks-for-password-even-with-passphrase)